# Delete all non cyrullic symbols from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I want have a field on my form, which can contain some symbols like #, $, etc. But for another case i want to have only letters, without any symbols. How do i cut all non letter symbols and leave all russian cyrullic letters

Here is small example:

i have string `"йцукен#$%йцукен"`

in the end want to get `"йцукен   йцукен"`

Comment: give us some real examples by saying what you have and what you want,we can't guess what you have. friend

Comment: What is "cyrullic"? I though Russian uses Cyrillic letters.

Comment: -1 for question not being clear. In the question, you describe as if you want to delete certain characters, but in the example, it looks like you want to replace a sequence of certain characters with a space. It is contradictory.

Comment: What you describe in the question cannot be true. You should not have `"йцукен#$%йцукен"` because it is not a valid Ruby string (However, `'йцукен#$%йцукен'` is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
'йцукен#$%йцукен'.gsub(/\P{Cyrillic}++/, ' ')
```

explanation:

\p{Cyrillic} is the character class for cyrillic letters.

\P{Cyrillic} contains all characters that are not cyrillic letters.

If you want to preserve other characters you can do it like this:

```
'123йцукен#$%йцукен456'.gsub(/[^\p{Cyrillic}0-9]++/, ' ')
```

Comment: does it means, i will get something like
`#=>йцукен йцукен`  ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid Ruby expression? I don't think so.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use super greedy quantifier here.

Answer (score 0):

brute force with a list of allowed characters

```
def filter(input, allowed)
  input.chars.inject('') do |result, char|
    result << char if allowed.include? char
    result
  end
end

test_string = 'abc$6&йцxyz'
allowed_characters = 'abcxyzйц'

puts filter(test_string, allowed_characters)
=> abcйцxyz
```

Answer (score -1):

The expression `"йцукен#$%йцукен"` that you have in the question is not a valid Ruby expression. The `#$` within double quotes works as interpolation. If you meant a string `'йцукен#$%йцукен'`, and if you wanted to replace sequences of characters like `'#%$'` with a space rather than just deleting them, then, the following can work.

```
'йцукен#$%йцукен'.tr('#%$', " ").squeeze(" ")
# => "йцукен йцукен"
```