# How to delete all symbols except cyrillic/latin alphabet from string?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

How to delete all symbols except cyrillic/latin alphabet from string?

```
str = 'детёныш test test ()&^*'
console.log(str.replace(/[^а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]/gi," "))
```

result:

дет ныш test test

Problem : lost symbol 'ё' in standart а-я range (абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя)

Comment: replace(/^а-яА-Я/gi," ") ???

Comment: This seems to work? or ё shouldn't be removed? Otherwise check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418222/delete-all-non-cyrullic-symbols-from-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably safer to use the [unicode block range for Cyrillic](http://unicode-table.com/en/sections/cyrillic/):

```
str.replace(/[^a-z\u0400-\u04FF]/gi," ");
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const str = 'детёныш test test ()&^*'

console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z\u0400-\u04FF]/gi, " "))
```